# Apache2 not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ubuntu-14.04

I'm a newbie developer at my first serious project! I'm trying to set up an AWS EC2 virtual machine using:

-Ubuntu 14.02.02

-Ruby 2.2.1

-Rails 4.2.4

-Apache2 last version.

After all configuration when I try to restart apache2 I get this error:

"mktemp: failed to create file via template ‘/tmp/tmp.XXXXXXXXXX’: No such file or directory
/etc/init.d/apache2: 91: /etc/init.d/apache2: cannot create : Directory nonexistent
 * 
 * The apache2 configtest failed. Not doing anything."

I've googled it without results. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: You should seriously consider starting with heroku or elastic beanstalk (I encourage the former). There's no badge of merit for hours spent learning devops...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the temp folder `/tmp` writable for your apache.

You can do this by running:
`sudo chmod 1777 /tmp`

Common right for /tmp are 1777, which ls shows as drwxrwxrwt.

**EDIT:**

If the folder is not existent first run:
`sudo mkdir /tmp`

Comment: Tried your answer I get this response: "chmod: cannot access '/tmp": No such file or directory'

Comment: Added a solution as EDIT to my previous answer.

Comment: Ok, but what would be tmp path? I tried the command you suggested me in the folder 'var'.

Comment: The temp path is a path where your apache stores temp-files... try google if you don't know what these are for.

Comment: Ok but what is the location/path where I have to run 'sudo mkdir /tmp'?

Comment: By adding a trailing `/` as in `/tmp` you say you want the root folder of your system. In the case of the tmp folder it is exactly where it should be. Apache will expect it there by default.

Comment: You can run the command wherever you want because you provide the full path where it should be. As in windows it would be `C:\tmp` in unix it is `/tmp`

Comment: Please accept my answer then. But you may consider the comment of Michal Szyndel as well. If you are not used to Devops you may struggle again in the future.